# Create double object with NA

Tags: r

How can I create a double object with an NA value.

I am writing a test case where the output is NA:

```
gt[2]$height
[1] NA

typeof(gt[2])
> "double"
```

Question is how can I create an object of type "double" with an NA value.

Comment: like this this? `df <- data.frame(x = c(1, NA, 3), y = 5:7); typeof(df$x)` you can simply do the vector `typeof(x = c(1, NA, 3))`, But I'm not totally sure what you mean by _double object_.

Answer (score 6):

By default, `NA` is a logical constant of length 1 used to represent missing values in data, and the type of `NA` can be modified by using one of the four types of `NA` such as  `NA_integer_`, `NA_real_`, `NA_complex_` and `NA_character_`.

For more info, please read the documentation page of `?NA`

Try this:

```
x <- numeric()
typeof(x)
# [1] "double"
y <- NA_real_
typeof(y)
# [1] "double"
y
# [1] NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mydata<-data.frame(height=NA)
mydata$height<-as.double(mydata$height)
typeof(mydata$height)
```